# Angular 2 TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'json'

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I am building a basic CRUD application that references a SSMS database, using an Angular 2 front end and a MVC back end. I am running into the error when i run my HTTPGet on any browser:

**TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'json'**

I have a debug point set for the service call but it doesn't get there, so I am assuming the issue is in the component somewhere..

I have googled for about a day and a half, and have found a lot of people that have other things in the place of the 'json', but I cannot find anyone else with this issue exactly. Below you will find the could for my Get. If there is any other snippets you need please let me know.

Here is my Get component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CorrectionCodeService } from '../Service/correctioncode.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { ICorrectionCode } from '../Models/ICorrectionCode';
import { DBOperation } from '../Shared/enum';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Global } from '../Shared/global';

@Component({

templateUrl: 'app/Components/correctioncode.component.html'

})

`enter code here`export class CorrectionCodeComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('modal') modal: ModalComponent;
corrCodes: ICorrectionCode[];
corrCode: ICorrectionCode;
msg: string;
indLoading: boolean = false;
form: FormGroup;
dbops: DBOperation;
modalTitle: string;
modalBtnTitle: string;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private _corrCodeService: CorrectionCodeService) { }



ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        id: [''],
        pgm_code_name: [''],
        rec_act_code: [''],
        rgln_Year: [''],
        rgln_type_name: [''],
        rgln_one_code: [''],
        rgln_two_code: [''],
        rgln_three_code: [''],
        rgln_title_text: [''],
        rgln_desc_text: [''],
        sevrty_code: [''],
        valdtn_value: [''],
        last_updt_dt: [''],
        last_updt_logn_id: [''],
        creat_dt: [''],
        creat_logn_id: [''],
        del_dt: [''],
        del_logn_id: [''],
        prev_rec_id: ['']
    });

    this.getCorrectionCodes();

} 
 getCorrectionCodes(): void {
    this.indLoading = true;
    this._corrCodeService.get(Global.BASE_CORRECTION_CODE_ENDPOINT)
        .subscribe(corrCodes => {
            this.corrCodes = corrCodes; this.indLoading = false;
        }, error => this.msg = <any>error);
}
```

And, here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
@Injectable()
export class CorrectionCodeService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    get(url: string): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'accept': 'applicationCache/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.get(url,options)
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            // .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)));

    }
```

here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';
import { CorrectionCodeComponent } from './Components/correctioncode.component';
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { CorrectionCodeService } from './Service/correctioncode.service';
import { UploadFileComponent } from './Components/uploadFile.component';
import { UploadFileService } from './Service/uploadFile.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, routing, Ng2Bs3ModalModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, CorrectionCodeComponent, HomeComponent,  UploadFileComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, CorrectionCodeService, UploadFileService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my controller:

```
using CorrectionCodeEditor.Models;
using CorrectionCodeEditor.Repository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace CorrectionCodeEditor.Controllers
{
    public class CorrectionCodeController : BaseAPIController
    {
        string ProgramAreaName = "FAS";
        private CorrectionCodeRepository context;
        public CorrectionCodeController()
        {

            context = new CorrectionCodeRepository();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var corrCodes = context.GetAllCorrectionCodes(ProgramAreaName).AsEnumerable();
                return ToJson(corrCodes);
        }
```

my ToJson method:

```
protected HttpResponseMessage ToJson(dynamic obj)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;
        }
```

and my Contextual DB Repository:

```
 public IEnumerable<CorrectionCode> GetAllCorrectionCodes(string pgm_area_name)
        {
            using (con)
            {
                 con.Open();
                var dP = new DynamicParameters();
                dP.Add("@ProgramAreaName", pgm_area_name);
                IEnumerable<CorrectionCode> corrCodeList = con.Query<CorrectionCode>("[mobile].[p_get_correction_codes_by_params]", dP, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                return corrCodeList;
            }
        }
```

EDIT#1 Compile Tile Error from Google Developer Tools while the screen displays "TypeError: error.json is not a function":

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (body.ts:36)
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (correctioncode.service.ts:12)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:75)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.ts:104)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:254)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:264)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:154)
```

here is a screenshot of the error readout in IE11 while the screen is saying "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'json'":

[image: ScreenSnip of IE11 compiling error]

Comment: Any specific reason why you are not using the HttpClient instead of Http? It will remove the need to call `.json` on `.map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())`; reference: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @joshvito not sure how to get the HTTPClient instead of the Http. i am a novice at the Angular 2 style of referencing.. Could you please explain what i would put in the package.json and systemjs.config.js

Comment: `map((response: Response) => response.json() as any)` can you try like this?

Comment: @tCoe, I liked you the angular doc's that walks you through setting up the new HttpClient. Follow this guide https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @stojevskimilan i tried what you suggested. it gave me a different error this time... SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: @joshvito i followed that through except i couldnt get the "@angular/common/http" module to be recognized. i am running angular 4.1.3 currently, but i did try to update to 4.3.1 without any change.

Comment: Hmm what about this? `map(response => response.json() as any).do(data => console.log(data))` what is result of this?

Comment: @tCoe, that is a problem, HttpClient is only available in angular 5.x.x; sorry about misleading. What is the exact compile time error / runtime error you are getting?

Comment: @joshvito please see the last edit. i include the console error from Google Dev Tools

Comment: @tCoe try adding a .catch to the http.get like this `return this._http.get(url, options)
          .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
          .catch((response: Response) => this.handleError(response));` you have to define a handleError function too

Comment: @tCoe are you testing this in browser Microsoft Edge?

Comment: @joshvito same error. BTW line 12 of the service is the .map((response:Response) => <any>response.json());

Comment: @BrianOgden only using Chrome and IE11, as i am in a state agency that doesn't approve of Edge

Comment: @BrianOgden i added a snip of the IE11 readout, which is the same as Edge.

Comment: are you importing the HttpModule into your application?

Comment: @joshvito I am have "import {Http} from @angular/http" in my service. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The angular code, posted above, looks good to me. I don't see any obvious errors. Are you using an IDE with ts-lint, maybe there is a not so obvious type error? I up-voted the question for you. Maybe next debug step is to try and add a link to a reproducible error on jsfiddle or the like.

Comment: @tCoe, no, usually somewhere in your application you either have to import the HttpModule into an @ NgModule definition or you add the 'Http' to a providers array. If you haven't done any of the above, Try importing {Http} into the component, and adding `
@Component({

templateUrl: 'app/Components/correctioncode.component.html'
providers: [Http]
})`

Comment: @joshvito I am importing the HttpModule into my app.module.ts. I will add the Code Snippet above. I am using VS 2015, i will try to get ts-lint installed on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out @joshvito was on the right track with the Angular being ok, just not completely correct. The problem is that in the tutorial i was following, it suggested that i edit the RouteConfig.ts to:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
           routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Default",
                            url: "{*anything}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                        );
        }
```

But the example was using Web Api not ASP.net, and because I am so new to Angular, I didn't know that I should have been editing the WebApiConfig.cs, which was expecting an action name that I was not passing in.   so when i changed my get method in my component to this:

```
getCorrectionCodes(): void {
        this.indLoading = true;
        this._corrCodeService.get(Global.BASE_CORRECTION_CODE_ENDPOINT+"get")
            .subscribe(corrCodes => {
                this.corrCodes = corrCodes; this.indLoading = false;
            }, error => this.msg = <any>error);
    }
```

Everything started to work as it should.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you to use the Http Client instead Http, because the first is deprecated. to use it simple:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   ...
  }
```

Of Course you should declare HttpClient also in your app.module in the same form that Http.

Comment: i am not using a version of angular that has the HttpClient, As discussed in the comments below the post.